# Collect strings after a foreach loop

Tags: c#, xml, foreach

Is it possible to collect the strings after a foreach loop? For example:

```
StringCollection col = new StringCollection();
XmlNodeList skillNameNodeList=SkillXML.GetElementsByTagName("name");
foreach (XmlNode skillNameNode in skillNameNodeList) 
{
  skillsName=skillNameNode.Attributes["value"].Value;  
}

col.Add(skillsName); //Return System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
```

I want to collect each skillsName and put them in a collection or a list so that I can use it later. Is it correct to use StringCollection? Or any other better suggestion?

Comment: Just call `col.Add(skillsName)` within the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you need to do the adding within the loop. I'd use a `List<string>` as it supports LINQ:

```
XmlNodeList skillNameNodeList=SkillXML.GetElementsByTagName("name");
List<string> skills = new List<string>();

foreach (XmlNode skillNameNode in skillNameNodeList) 
{
     skills.Add(skillNameNode.Attributes["value"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also create the list directly using LINQ

```
var list =
 SkillXML.GetElementsByTagName("name")
 .Cast<XmlNode>()
 .Select(n => n.Attributes["value"].Value)
 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
XmlNodeList skillNameNodeList=SkillXML.GetElementsByTagName("name");
foreach (XmlNode skillNameNode in skillNameNodeList) 
{ 
  myList.Add(skillNameNode.Attributes["value"].Value);
}
```

There may be a neater way to do it via linq. It would be something like the below (disclaimer: not tested).

```
var myList = SkillXML.GetElementsByTagName("name").Cast<XmlNode>().Select(n => n.Attributes["value"].Value).ToList();
```